# Docker: Push layers of every stage to cache

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a multi-stage docker file that looks something like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.10.12-alpine3.18 as base

# Do stuff...


FROM base as test

# Do stuff

ENTRYPOINT ["myapp-test"]


FROM base as prod

# Do stuff

ENTRYPOINT ["myapp"]
```

Both the prod and test stage needs the base stage, but prod doesn't depend on test so when I run `docker build -t myapp .` the test stage is correctly skipped, and vice-versa. My issue is with building the cache. When I add the option: `--cache-to type=registry,ref=<registry>/<cache-image>,mode=max`, the image will only contains the layers from the target that is being built, so when I build the other with `--cache-from ...` most of the layers are missing from the cache.

An obvious solution is to build 2 different image for each target, but I was wondering if there was maybe not a cleaner way where I could have a single image with all stages (and their layers) built into it?

Comment: Does it change anything if you use `docker buildx build --target prod ...`? Usually if you use a multistage build without specifying a target it will build everything through to the bottom of the file.

Comment: That's based on the legacy builder I think. With the buildkit builder, stages that are not needed are skipped: "BuildKit only builds the stages that the target stage depends on" (https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/). I tried not specifying the target but only the last stage and its dependencies were built.

Comment: maybe to fkip the problem on its head is there a reason you dont want to use two separate images. Generally id have 3 docker files here. ONe for the base, one for test and one for prod. This means when auditing git commits etc its easy to know what a commit was affecting. just form the files it touched. Other wise you have 3 diffrerent reasons for changing this docker file.

Comment: Using 3 different files instead of 1 with multi-stage goes against every docker recommendations I've read, both by users and the docker documentation itself. It basically means that to build "prod" you need to run a docker command for each of it's dependencies, one at at time. It also means that your build process is tied to a specific number of dockerfiles and you can't add stages without having to change the ci/cd pipeline. And all of that just so you you can see from the filename what you are changing? I would reconsider your approach if I were you, it isn't good.